# Visual Studio 2013 Unable to build/rebuild/clean until restart

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build

Im facing this problem for a few days already. I cant build/rebuild/clean a solution/project after like ten minutes (different projects other people work on too, but Im the only one with this problem). When I try to, the error list is empty. I have to restart Visual Studio to get it working again.

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project3, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project4, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Project5, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 5 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Not anywhere near enough info here.  There's GOT to be something in the output window.  If not, uninstall, reinstall.

Comment: Search for "Error:" in the output window. Another thing you can try is deleting your projects' bin and obj folders.

Answer (score 1):

Check solution configuration properties. You have to checks project you want to build under active build configuration.

[image]